# Импорт большой БД MySQL на локальный сервер

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, база-данных, mysql

Есть: дамп БД MySQL в архиве gz весит 81 метр, а распакованная более 500.
Denwer 3. На нем установлен движок дле.

Никак не могу импортировать эту базу в движок. Если действовать методами самого движка - тупо виснет  на середине процесса, а импорт через phpMyAdmin тоже вешается. Выдает ошибки.
В конфигах пхп и мускула увеличил объем аплоада до 512 метров, не помогло.

Есть идеи как мне сделать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если дамп в SQL-формате, то самое лучшее решение - развернуть его через консоль.

```
mysql.exe --user=user --password=password name_database < file.sql
```

Comment: Для общего развития: на винде точно работает `<` ?

Comment: И `<`, и `>`, и даже `|` тоже работает

Comment: Так, честно говоря никогда не пробовал работать с мускулом в консоле.
Итак я зашел в mysql.exe
набираю там команду
 --user=DosTavki5 --password=****** DosTavki5 < dump.sql (или здесь полный путь к файлу указывать?)
После этого ничего не происходит, консоль просто переключается на следующую строку.
->

Comment: Заходить в mysql не нужно. Нужно выполнить команду в консоли системы.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Хоть и помучился я порядочно)

Comment: А подскажите как будет выглядеть эта команда если импортировать в базу дамп сжатый zip или gzip?